# first order differential

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am just wondering if it would be possible if someone could explain this question to me. I do not want any help with the maths, I would just like help trying to understand the wording of the problem.

Q: In Problems 13 to 15, find a solution (or solutions) of the differential equation **not obtainable by specializing the constant** in your solution of the original problem.

equation 13 is:$x\sqrt{1-y^2}dx+y\sqrt{1-x^2}dy=0$

as I said I would not like help with the problem just what the bold section in the question actually means.

My guess is I am finding and actual value for y. That is a guess so I am not sure if I am correct.

Comment: >_> separable differential equations

Answer (score 2):

write equation in the form
$$\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}dy=-\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$ and integrate.